# CSS pixels / em units diffent on diffent screens

Tags: css, screen, pixel, units-of-measurement

I face the same problem for some months.
If I define any sizes or positions in pixels or in EM units, it is differently translated on different screens and resolutions within the same browsers.

For example - I have Dell display 24" 1920x1080pixels and my colleague has 24" older display by Dell with 1600x1200pixels resolution. 
The problem is, that the same webpage is displayed differently.
For example, when I want to have two buttons on the same line without linebreak and I set proper pixel width in CSS, so it is not line-broken on my display, it is broken on my colleagues display, so I have to set several pixels less size. The same works for EMs.

One another example:

[image]

Position absolute and I am using negative right position of element to have it next to scrollbar. On my computer it is fine, on my colleagues notebook it is bearly visible.

What is the relation between the units and pixel sizes on the screen?
How can I safely write css sheet in CSS3 and HTML5 doctype to have the right compatibility on all resolutions?

The same problem is with buttons / text inputs, when I use just font-size and padding to set the size of buttons and inputs. It looks different rely on resolution of display.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You must use an unit that is relative to the viewport, like 
[`vw` and `vh`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html)

Answer (score 0):

`em` or `rem` are relative to the font-size defined for the current font. Do you have the font-size defined for body?

Also read this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: So the best practice would be to have body pixel sized font-size and after that using em units or rem units for all the positions, sizes, margins, paddings?

Comment: I am just saying that if you have your own css, you need to define the font-size for body in px, otherwise if you have Bootstrap or Foundation keep in mind that they define a 16px default font-size so 1em/1rem will be 16px.

Comment: So, if I understand - using non relative units is not good, because there is a variety of ways, how different devices count absolute pixel units, so it is important to use relative units to be able to get same result on different devices / screens and to have the right counting of relative units, is important to have font-size in pixels defined as default for root element. Rem units are relative to the parent element, not the root element of the whole page. And mentioning bootstrap is good as well as an inspiration.